# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'NSInteger' (aka 'int')

Tags: ios, ios5, xcode4.2, long-integer, nsuinteger

I am trying to assign a variable with type 'long long' to a type NSUInteger, What is the correct way to do that?

my code line:

```
expectedSize = response.expectedContentLength > 0 ? response.expectedContentLength : 0;
```

where `expectedSize` is of type NSUInteger and return type of `response.expectedContentLength` is of type '`long long`'. The variable `response` is of type `NSURLResponse`.

The compile error shown is:

> Semantic Issue: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long
>   long' to 'NSUInteger' (aka 'unsigned int')

Comment: You can do an explicit cast, or did you know this and is your question about more than the "how"?  Here's the line with the explicit cast:
`expectedSize = response.expectedContentLength > 0 ? (NSUInteger)response.expectedContentLength : 0;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really just a cast, with some range checking:

```
const long long expectedContentLength = response.expectedContentLength;
NSUInteger expectedSize = 0;

if (NSURLResponseUnknownLength == expectedContentLength) {
    assert(0 && "length not known - do something");
    return errval;
}
else if (expectedContentLength < 0) {
    assert(0 && "too little");
    return errval;
}
else if (expectedContentLength > NSUIntegerMax) {
    assert(0 && "too much");
    return errval;
}

// expectedContentLength can be represented as NSUInteger, so cast it:
expectedSize = (NSUInteger)expectedContentLength;
```

Comment: `< 0` check is not correct. The value -1 means "no expectation that can be arrived at regarding expected content length" (see NSURLResponse.h)

Comment: @Dmitry added case to example. it's a very specific implementation detail, which would have been caught. it was meant to demonstrate the process, rather than be a perfect and complete implementation (it still is not).

Answer (score 11):

you could try the conversion with NSNumber:

```
  NSUInteger expectedSize = 0;
  if (response.expectedContentLength) {
    expectedSize = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong: response.expectedContentLength].unsignedIntValue;
  }
```